# Is it possible to define CDI Stereotypes in Scala?

Tags: scala, annotations, cdi

To define a CDI stereotype, i would need to define a runtime annotation. 
In scala, i tried this:

```
@Stereotype
@Target(Array(ElementType.METHOD))
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
//... my stereotype annotations 
class MyStereotype extends ClassfileAnnotation{}
```

But found this problem:

> Implementation restriction: subclassing Classfile does not make your
>   annotation visible at runtime. If  that is what you want, you must
>   write the annotation class in Java.

Is it possible, using scala 2.9.1, to define runtime annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely a Scala issue where runtime renentive annotations must be done in Java. So CDI (as well as other stereotypes) should be done in Java.